# How to unmount a device if another is mounted on the same path

Tags: linux, mount

I have a situation like this:

```
mount /dev/hdb /mnt
mount /dev/hdc /mnt
```

How do I unmount /dev/hdb without first unmounting /dev/hdc?

Comment: What happens when you execute `umount /dev/hdb`?

Answer (score 0):

Reboot you server, there is no other way.

Comment: Luckily, the case is not so bad.